# Out Of Office - Do not automatically reply to mail addressed to groups

Tags: lotus-notes

There used to be an option when setting Out Of Office to prevent automatic replies for mail addressed to groups. It no longer appears to be available in Notes 10/11 Does anyone know how to achieve this functionality, it seems quite a basic requirement so I feel I am missing something?

Many thanks.

As it was in Notes 7.

[image]

Comment: For others coming across this. Discovered via the HCL support forum that that is the way it is, feature dropped by IBM due to technical issues. You can work round it via mailin dbs but that is a pretty poor solution I feel.

Comment: What does Notes 10 / 11 provide now?

Comment: If one member of a group sets Out Of Office senders of mail to that group receive an out of office notice from the user.